# Document header not evaluated below ie10

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have a Wordpress site and created a custom theme for it. The pure CSS and HTML test version (without making it an actual Wordpress theme) is displayed 100% correct.

As soon as I make it dynamic and create a WP theme, IE 10 is ok, but IE10 compatibility and below somehow evaluate my document head as part of the body. It is displayed in IE html view window like this:

[image]

'!!!' is my actual title. All the CSS and meta information should be before my title, and somehow the head ending metatag is not displayed but it is present in my html markup.

SourceCode view is displayed as:

[image]

Head ending and everything in place. However there are two leading whitespace before DOCTYPE declaration, I have no idea how they got there, cleaned up every possible place in my source files. If I copy and paste their value into notepad two question marks "??" are displayed instead of whitespace.

Have never seen anything like this before. Mozilla and Chrome are 100% ok.

Comment: You need to post the source as text, not a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody has the same problem I found the answer.

My page.php and functions.php file of the Wordpress theme was utf-8 encoded that sometimes puts leading whitespace in the source code. This was enough for IE. I made it ANSI encoded and now it is ok.